# tfs project alerts

Tags: tfs, project, alerts

the 4 project alerts in TFS are good but I need some more of mine in them. The important one i want is when i create a new bug in TFS i want an email to be sent out.
Is there a way i can create a new alert in the project alerts? If so how?

Answer (score 6):

This is what you are looking for: [Team Foundation Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) - look for Alert Editor.
Once that is installed you will be able to customize alerts as you wish. It will add a new node under each team project in Team Explorer.